# Endgame and Middlegame tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Both *endgame* and *middlegame* are one word each in chess literature, but the tag for endgame is currently [end-game](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/end-game).  Is there an easy way to fix this, or do we have to un-tag everything that has endgame right now and then re-tag it?.

The reason that tag synonyms don't work is that "endgame" is considered to be an alternate spelling of "end-game" so nothing can be tagged "endgame" and the tag synonym cannot be created until the "endgame" tag exists.

N.B. I created a [middlegame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middlegame) tag in order to avoid this problem with that tag.

Comment: Funny, I also tried yesterday to change the tag on all the "end-game" questions, and failed of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exercising the new mod tools, I fixed the [endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endgame) tag.